# Flutter getting bool out of Future<bool> but got null assigned to the Boolean variable

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting an error when I try to get the boolean result out of the `Future<bool>` in Flutter. The scenario is, I am trying to query in the Firebase Firestore associated with my project, and check if the query contains no item. Therefore, I use this snippet to do this query and return it as a `Future<bool>`:

```
static Future<bool> checkDupTitle (String uid, String title) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection(DBCollection.summits.toString())
          .where(SummitWhirlwindModel.UID, isEqualTo: uid)
          .where(SummitWhirlwindModel.TITLE, isEqualTo: title)
          .snapshots().isEmpty;
}
```

To get the boolean result out of the `Future<bool>`, I have tried both `async`/`await` and `.then` syntax. Unfortunately, neither of them works. For example, when I use `.then`, I get the boolean value of `containsDup` assigned to `null`, below is the function call:

```
bool isValid(String uID) {
    Future<bool> containsDupFuture = checkDupTitle(uID, this.title.value);
    bool containsDup;
    containsDupFuture.then((value) => containsDup = value);
    return !containsDup;
}
```

Can anyone help me with this problem? I am new to flutter and when I look up the related questions on Stackoverflow, I am not able to get any valuable answers to my case. Thank you so much for answering this question ahead!!!

Comment: The function you pass to `then` is executed, once the `Future` has completed. Meanwhile, the program continues executing. In your example, the return statement is called – and since `containsDub` has not been set – it returns null.

Comment: So could you please let me know how to eliminate this race condition? @StefanGaller

Comment: I believe I only set `containsDup` inside of the `.then` clause where it waits for the `Future` complete.

Comment: Future<bool> isValid(String uID) async {
    bool containsDup = await checkDupTitle(uID, this.title.value);
    return !containsDup;
}

Comment: @StefanGaller Thanks for your answer. However, functions marked `async` must have a return type assignable to `Future`.  That's said, this won't work when we wanna get `bool` out of `Future<bool>`.

Comment: You will always get a `Future` from an `async` function. You can use a `FutureBuilder` to use the `Future` in your UI.

Comment: @StefanGaller There isn't a UI for this part of the code. That's why I don't use `FutureBuilder` because it's not in a clear widget tree.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  static Future<bool> checkDupTitle (String uid, String title) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(DBCollection.summits.toString())
        .where(SummitWhirlwindModel.UID, isEqualTo: uid)
        .where(SummitWhirlwindModel.TITLE, isEqualTo: title)
        .get().then((QuerySnapshot snapshot){
          if(snapshot.docs.length >0){
            return true;
          }else{
            return false;
          }
    });
  }
```

Be sure to initialize the function:

```
@override
void initState()   {
checkDupTitle (String uid, String title);  //provide uid,title
                     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, this still gives me a null when getting the `boolean` out of the `Future<bool>`.

Comment: Did you initialize the function?,I edited the answer.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha! But where should I put this initialization of `intiState` and where will it be called?

Comment: anywhere inside class, or just below your function.

Comment: If I want to use `initState`, it must be in a class that extends a `State`. In my case, this class is not under a `State` so I can't initialize the function in this way.